# ROS on IOS devices

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I seem to remember seeing an email on the old developer list about someone working on cross compiling ROS to IOS devices, but I can't seem to find it. Is there anyway (beside using the OSC interface) to run ROS on an iTouch/iPad? Specifically I would love to grab images from the camera, audio from the microphone, play sounds through the speaker, and stream this info to a roscore on another machine.
Thanks.

Kevin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12090/ros-on-ios-devices/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2011-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's been done in the past see http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2009/04/03/ros-ipod-touchiphone  The documentation is quite out of date(2 years), and we're working on making cross compiling easier.  Hopefully if you want something quick this will get you going.  If you do get it working please update the [rospod wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rospod) with what you did.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1